# NSTextField with number formatter does not accept padding character only

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumberformatter, nsformatter

I have a NSTextField with a number formatter set this way:

```
NSNumberFormatter *myFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[myFormatter setFormatWidth:7];
[myFormatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
[myFormatter setMinimumSignificantDigits:0];

[myFormatter setMinimum:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];
[myFormatter setMaximum:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:9999999]];
[myClientIDTextField setFormatter:myFormatter];
```

Everything works as expected, but I cannot input "0" or "00"
or "000" and so on in the textfield, if I do a sheet appears
on the window, saying that my input was invalid. My expected behaviour
would be that inputting "0" should be validated as "0000000".
Does anybody have a clue of why this is happening and how to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to be able to enter leading zeroes? The trick is understanding the way NSFormatter objects work. It's not simple or easy and takes effort. If you get really good at them you are 25% ready to write a spreadsheet app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the format as @"0000000", then it requires 7 digits and will fill in 0s where a digit doesn't exist.

```objectivec
// Objective-C
NSNumberFormatter *myFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[myFormatter setFormat:@"0000000"];
[myFormatter setMinimum:@0];
[myFormatter setMaximum:@9999999];
[myClientIDTextField setFormatter:myFormatter];
```

```swift
// Swift
let myFormatter = NumberFormatter()
myFormatter.format = "0000000"
myFormatter.minimum = 0
myFormatter.maximum = 9999999
myClientIDTextField.formatter = myFormatter
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it works ! now it formats correctly and accepts zeros ! Thanks again

Comment: @AlfonsoTesauro Sure, if you could accept this as an answer that would be much appreciated.